# Injection from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I'm doing some set theory problems. They ask me to find the cardinality of some specific set and it seems that it would often be useful to have a function that mapped any tuple of real numbers to a real number.

Is there a simple function I can use?

Comment: Maybe try to do something a little simpler, try to think about the case from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven That is nowhere near an injection...

Comment: Maybe try sending an n-tuple $(a_{1}, \ldots, a_{n})$ to a the point $0.a_{1}a_{2}\ldots a_{n}$. I don't know if it's going to work but something you can try.

Comment: @InsigMath Well, it's not really that simpler since if I knew that, I could just extend it for any tuple (at least I think I could)

Comment: @user135520 That would work if $a_n$ were integers...

Comment: @5xum: Well, almost. $(12,3)$ and $(1,23)$ would both map to 0.123.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an injection from $[0,1]^n$ to $[0,1]$, you can always map

$$(0.a_1^1a_2^1a_3^1a_4^1\dots, 0.a_1^2a_2^2\dots, \dots, 0.a_1^na_2^n\dots)$$
to $$0.a_1^1a_1^2a_1^3\dots a_1^na_2^1a_2^2\dots a_2^n\dots$$

Taking care of some edge-cases (for example, where do you put $0.3\overline9$?), this is the way to go in my opinion.

Comment: That should work great, yeah. I'm just having trouble seeing why 0.3999999... is a problem.

Comment: The infinite-nines case is actually not a problem in this direction. If only you decide not to use a representation for the _inputs_ that ends in infinite nines, you don't risk creating one as the _output_ either. The only thing that goes "wrong" with the naive interlacing is that the mapping is then not _surjective_ because for example 0.090909... is not produced. But Cantor-Bernstein will take care of that easily.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Indeed, you are correct. However, it is still important (in the definition of the function) to tell where infinte nines plot to, otherwise the function is not well defined.

Comment: @5xum: Well, if you decide always to use the representation of the input that ends in infinite _zeroes_ when possible, then the infinite-nines case _will never arise_ and therefore doesn't need to map to anywhere.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Of course. I am simply saying that in order to have a well defined function, you *need* to decide on one of the input formats, as depending on that, you get two different functions. Both are fine, but without picking one, you don't have a well defined function.

Comment: Okay, fair enough.